# Best method of interpolation?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I am learning different interpolation methods, and their pros and cons. Which interpolation method do you think is the best for practical use? If you can give me links to research papers about various interpolation methods, or may be just share your knowledge, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: B-splines - one of methods. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline

Comment: zunzun.com has a bunch of them implemented, I recommend that site.  It will also run them all and give you the best-fitting ones.

Comment: What is the dimension of the space you are working on. Sample points on a line (1d spline/interpolation)? A square? A large 3d dataset? or even multi-dimensional problems?

Comment: A large 3d dataset.

Comment: Different interpolations have differential features, especially smoothness, you can interpolate a function into different spaces, for example, piecewise linear/quadratic, or spline which requires the continuity of the derivatives. Same thing applies for a certain data set, you could have drastically different interpolations based on the same dataset.

Comment: Sorry, but you should give more details in your question if you want relevant answers. 1) How do you mean the "best"? Rate of convergence, stability, smoothness, shapes, etc.
2) "large 3d set". What is the domain like? 3) How do  you measure the error? sup-norm, Lp-norm. etc?